# Compatibility mode in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, compatibility, ie8-compatibility-mode

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="edge" />
```

> This forces Internet Explorer 8 to render in the most recent mode. For instance; If IE-8 used this would behave like using a value of IE=8, but when IE 9 is available that will be the mode that IE=edge will render in.

This works fine for :

- All the normal view from IE-8 to IE-11
- The Compatibility view in IE-10 & IE-11

The current layout:

[image]

But when the site tested in IE-8 & IE-9 Compatibility mode, The layout breaks.

The Layout after breaking:
[image]

Is there any solution or `<meta>` tag to add so that the layout works well from all IE-8 to IE-11 Compatibility mode ?

Comment: You need to explain what "the layout breaks" means in detail. There's no way to fix a problem if nobody knows what it is

Comment: when you specify IE=EDGE the corresponding IE version will try to render the page in standards mode when you view it in the browser....  ideally your page should be build in standards more so that it displays well in other browser and then for IE you use this meta.

Comment: @Bojangles: Please check the updated one. I added images for both the cases.

Comment: @Bojangles : Only in the Compatibility mode of IE-8 & IE-9 this will break & for rest works fine.

Comment: What `doctype` are you using? Are you using `display:inline-block` for those `divs`?

Comment: @Vucko: I am using <!DOCTYPE html> and also using `display:inline-block` for those divs.